# get return value from async function which is using forEach

Tags: foreach, promise, async-await

I am using a async function which return a value after searching, value returned before foreach completion.

```
async function accessSpreadsheet(orderId){
                let tax="";
                var doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('54345u7iJzvl59oeyT_9np1Xd2_54654656');
                await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
                const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
                const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
                const rows =await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
                    offset:1
                });             
                rows.forEach(row =>{
                    if(orderId == row.orderid){
                        tax=row.imei1;
                    }
                });


                return tax;
        }
        console.log(accessSpreadsheet("88280"));
```

I want `tax` value with this function but got only pending promise like `Promise { <pending> }`
. how can I get tax ?

Comment: The `forEach` has nothing to do with this, it's synchronous. Btw you really should be using `find` instead.

Comment: Use `accessSpreadsheet("88280").then(console.log);` or `console.log(await accessSpreadsheet("88280"));` instead. There is no way to get the future result immediately.